# VS 2022 bug? How to correct the build icon animation being constantly on

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I've noticed with the last couple of updates to Visual Studio 2022 that after rebuilding that the icon  on the status bar stays and animates...  Normally this icon would disappears after the rebuild/build completes.

[image]

Is there some setting to turn this off... kind of annoying.  Or is this a bug that Microsoft has yet to fix?

Thanks!

**Follow up**: As of Aug 9, 2023,  Microsoft says this is fixed. Check this [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/there-is-an-animated-icon-in-the-status-/10289949).

Well... as of today(8/21/2023) the problem still exists with in v17.7.1...

Comment: Might be a bug that Microsoft has yet to fix.  I've seen this happen before too.  I am using 17.7.0 Preview 2 right now and I don't remember seeing this anymore, but maybe it hasn't cropped up yet.  Pretty sure just a few versions ago it was still a thing.

Comment: @TimothyG. - it is still a thing as of 17.6.3 which is what I am currently running.

Answer (score 4):

It's a bug. It's been reported a good number of times, and this is the bug report that's still open and "Under Investigation":
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/there-is-an-animated-icon-in-the-status-/10289949

I'm on 17.6.5, and it's been bothering me too.

Comment: Well according to microsoft this particular issue should be fixed... I guess we shall see.  Im on 17.7.0

Answer (score 0):

I'm on 17.4.4 and I can confirm that this issue is not fixed for this version. A restart of VS makes it go away. If I had to guess (which I don't) and suggest a fix to the Microsoft developers, it feels to me like a missing call to Refresh on the control that contains the animated icon on the status bar which should happen when build completes but maybe doesn't.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: My answer is perfectly clear. It address the Update portion of the original question and clearly describes what I perceive as the issue.